# How to share a USB drive via Samba without modifying the drive's permissions?

Tags: fedora, samba, usb-drive

I'm trying to share a USB connected drive via samba as is but every howto online on how to do it requires that I change the drive's permissions and the selinux security context. On the latter I can compromise since I don't think it changes the files on the drive (from what I researched, anyways) but changing the permissions it's a no-no, how can I do that? I'm on Fedora 35 server.

Comment: What filesystem type is used on the USB drive? (Does it even have Unix-style permissions? Can it support extended attributes, and is such support enabled? If the answer to these questions is "no", the permissions and SELinux contexts are respectively controlled by mount options. Changing such options won't cause any changes to the drive.)

Comment: *every howto online on how to do it requires that I change the drive's permissions* - I've yet to see that.

Comment: @telcoM it's ext4 encrypted.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov maybe I should've written 'folder' instead of drive but feel free to link one that doesn't. I want to make the entire drive available.

Comment: Changing SeLinux context is not required, you can use SeLinux variables. `force user = root` should be enough to be able to read all files regardless of their permissions.

Answer (score 1):

These two will allow you to read any files regardless of their permissions:

1. smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = GROUPNAME
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    guest account = nobody
    map to guest = Bad User

[USB]
   path = /mnt/disk
   public = yes
   only guest = yes
   writable = no
   printable = no
   force user = root
```

2. `sudo setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro 1`
3. `sudo service smb restart`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know of the variable. I don't want to allow access to guests, setting `only guest = no` would accomplish that?